# IValidatableObject is returning not all code paths return a value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following inside my model class,, to trim a value:-

```
 [MetadataType(typeof(ITSwitchPort_Validation))]
    [Bind(Include = "PortNumber,SwitchID,TechnologyID")]
    public partial class ITSwitchPort : IValidatableObject
    {
        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(PortNumber))
            {
                PortNumber = PortNumber.Trim();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But i am receiving the following error :-

```
Error   1   '.....Validate(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext)': not all code paths return a value
```

Answer (score 1):

Error itself says about the problem, function `Validate` has a return type but you are returning nothing.

Your method assumes return type `IEnumerable<ValidationResult>`, but you are not returning that type from function.

Comment: the problem when i specify Void instead of IEnumerable<> i got the following error :- 'IT.Models.ITSwitchPort' does not implement interface member 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.IValidatableObject.Validate(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext)'.  cannot implement 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.IValidatableObject.Validate(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext)' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult>'.

Comment: This is because you are implementing Interface `IValidatableObject` and need to override `Validate` method. If you have nothing to return try `return null;` or a object of type `IEnumerable<ValidationResult>`